# Lanzar ShareIntent y cambiar de Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

No sé si es posible hacerlo, imagino que sí pero no doy con la forma. Quiero lanzar un ShareIntent para compartir datos de mi app con otras app con la peculiaridad de que una vez se haya compartido los datos con la app seleccionada, mi app cambie de Activity.

He probado con este código pero no funciona, si lanza el ShareIntent pero no cambia de activity.
¿Alguien sabe si se pueden hacer las dos cosas y cómo?

Gracias

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mira mi actividad "+m.getActividad());
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setClass(NuevoAvaInf.this,Menu.class);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar hacer algo así:

```
//iniciamos la nueva activity
Intent tuSegundaActivdad = new Intent(tuActivityActual.this, tuSegundoActivity.class); 
startActivity(tuSegundadActividad);

//cerramos la activity actual
getActivity().finish();

//tu código modificado
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mira mi actividad "+m.getActividad());
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, "send");
```

Espero te sirva